# anchor symbol doesn't work in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, anchor

I have thess lines in .htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+)-pg-1\.html$ page.php?b=$1&pg=1 [L,NC,NS]
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+)-pg-([0-9]+)\.html$ page.php?b=$1&pg=$2#nv [NE,L,NC,NS]
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+)-pg-([0-9]+)-lo\.html$ page.php?b=$1&pg=$2&lo=1 [L,NC,NS]
```

but it doesn't work as I expected it. It seems it doesn't go to #nv in the page.
What is the problem with that rule?

Comment: I suspect the URL not starting (`^`) where you think.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rewrite to an URL with hashes: they're resolved at the client-side, not at the server-side. But you can organize a redirect to such a page with `R`:

```
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+)-pg-([0-9]+)\.html$  page.php?b=$1&pg=$2#nv [NE,L,NC,NS,R=302]
```

Comment: I tried that you say but url of the page changed completely and showed document root of site !

Comment: Are there any other rules in that file, that may relate to `page.php` itself?

Comment: I put all the lines related to page.php in the question. please have a look at it.

Comment: What happens if you tr to navigate to `page.php` directly?

Comment: I need those query strings .

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to debug the rewritten url, as obviously rule is processed. You cannot make a rewrite with hash - it will just be cut off the request, so redirect is the only way; but it has to be passed through as it is. If you cannot navigate to plain `page.php` to check how it's processed, I'm afraid there's little I can do to help further.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally used jQuery to solve it.

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: YPosition}, 3000 );
```

I don't know if it will be useful for you.

If you don't know the height of the boxes you can use ID to reference the place:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#ElementID").offset().top-XXX }, 1000);
```

I have to subtract some pixels to the top because I have a navigation bar fixed.